# Searching emoji from varchar column returns different record

Tags: mysql, emoji, utf8mb4

I'm using MySQL5.6. The DB character set is utf8mb4.
When I search emoji as below, I got unexpected results.

```
mysql> SELECT id, hex(title) FROM tags WHERE title = 0xF09F9886;
+-----+------------+
| id  | hex(title) |
+-----+------------+
| 165 | F09F9886   |
| 166 | F09F9884   |
+-----+------------+
```

It should return only id=165. Does anyone know this why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found how to fix it. It was a problem of collation. I used default collation value, I presume it's `utf8mb4_general_ci`. When I changed that utf8mb4_bin, MySQL returned right result.

You can change collation as below.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
```